# Create Temp Table From Stored Procedure Result

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create a temp table from a stored procedure result set without having to specify column datatypes? If not, is it possible to create a physical table at least from the SP? The reason I am asking is because I have an SP that returns too many columns for me to declare in a create table command.

Is there something like

create table  from

where columns do not need to specified and sql automaticly determines column attributes??

I am running SQL server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See following  [question from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure). According to this question you can use

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getDatabaseList
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM sys.databases
END

 SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM 
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;','EXEC getDatabaseList')

-- create temp table as usual, select , update or drop table
```

Comment: You *may* need to add "SET FMTONLY OFF" before the stored procedure execution inside the OPENROWSET function.

Comment: I got the following error. I guess I don't have enough privileges?   SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Atilla Ozgur and thanks for the tip @spaghettidba! I'm pretty sure it will work but I will have to talk to our DBA about getting the permissions. That technique will save me a lot of time once i implement it!